# Nativescript Vue conditional v-template not working

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a ListView which renders this:

```
    <ListView v-for="(item, index) in items" height="500">
       <v-template v-if="index < items.length - 1">
          <GridLayout rows="*, *", columns="220,130,*"> 
              <TextField hint="Project Item" row="0" col="0" />
              <TextField hint="Price" row="0" col="1" />
              <Button text="X" row="0" col="2" />
          </GridLayout>
       </v-template>                         

 <!-- render if index reaches last element -->

       <v-template v-if="index == items.length - 1">
          <GridLayout rows="*, *", columns="220,130,*"> 
            <TextField hint="Project Item" row="0" col="0" />
            <TextField hint="Price" row="0" col="1" />
            <Button text="index" row="0" col="2" />
          </GridLayout>
       </v-template>           

    </ListView>
```

The second `v-template` block should be the one rendered if the index reaches last element of the array.

This is the array I have:

```
items: [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ]
```

Whats being rendered on the page is rather the value of each element: `1, 2, 3, 1 ...` in TextField without any buttons defined in my code.

**How do I get the conditional to work?**

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 3):

`<v-template>` uses `if`, not `v-if`. Also, you can't access `items` in the in the `if` (as described [here](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/elements/components/list-view/#using-listview-with-multiple-v-template-blocks)).
Also, you should use `for` instead of `v-for`.

So this is what you can do:

1- Change the template to:

```
    <ListView for="(item, index) in listItems" height="500">
       <v-template if="!item.isLast">
          <GridLayout rows="*, *", columns="220,130,*"> 
              <TextField hint="Project Item" row="0" col="0" />
              <TextField hint="Price" row="0" col="1" />
              <Button text="X" row="0" col="2" />
          </GridLayout>
       </v-template>                         

 <!-- render if index reaches last element -->

       <v-template if="!item.isLast">
          <GridLayout rows="*, *", columns="220,130,*"> 
            <TextField hint="Project Item" row="0" col="0" />
            <TextField hint="Price" row="0" col="1" />
            <Button text="index" row="0" col="2" />
          </GridLayout>
       </v-template>           

    </ListView>
```

This would use another list `listItems`, which you could build with a computed prop like so:

```
computed: {
  listItems() {
    return this.items.map((item, index) => {
      item.isLast = index === items.length - 1;
      return item;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Also he should have to use just `for` instead of `v-for`

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use `for` instead of `v-for`. Also, For the index in `ListView`, there is a default `$index` variable so you can use it as below.

```
<ListView for="item in items" height="500">
   <v-template v-if="$index < items.length - 1">
      <GridLayout rows="*, *", columns="220,130,*"> 
          <TextField hint="Project Item" row="0" col="0" />
          <TextField hint="Price" row="0" col="1" />
          <Button text="X" row="0" col="2" />
      </GridLayout>
   </v-template>
```

```
   <v-template v-if="$index == items.length - 1">
      <GridLayout rows="*, *", columns="220,130,*"> 
        <TextField hint="Project Item" row="0" col="0" />
        <TextField hint="Price" row="0" col="1" />
        <Button text="index" row="0" col="2" />
      </GridLayout>
   </v-template>           

</ListView>
```